# How do I get "The Full Truth" achievement?

Tags: pony-island

I got stuck in this last achievement of mine.
From some reason, I can't get to ask the 5th question "How did I get here?".
I think I did everything I need in order to see it:
I asked 3 of the questions in the cave of truth, and another one in the ####### option at act 2, and now I think I should find the last one in act 3 in the [hidden area of the butterflies puzzle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVc1u.jpg).
But I still getting only the 3 questions I saw in the cave.
What should I do?

[image]